# Shapes with $7$ lines of symmetry

Tags: symmetry

I am trying to find shapes with $7$ lines of symmetry. Regular $7$-gon(Heptagon) has this property. but can you give example of other shapes with $7$ lines of symmetry? (I know I can draw an small circle on every vertices of the Heptagon and still have the symmetry lines but I want to see other examples)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagram

Comment: [This](https://eschersket.ch/) will let you draw as many as you like, per Hume2's answer (under "symmetries", click "rosette", set "Nrot" to 7 and "Nref" to 0, and draw away).

Comment: @user3482749 Wow ! this is very amazing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Here you have a shape with 7 axes of symmetry. The axes of symmetry always have to be arranged in this shape. Now you can obtain any shape with 7 axes of symmetry by a simple algorithm:

1. Draw anything you want into one of the segments. I painted a triangle (marked by red colour).
2. Paste the same thing into the other segments. (marked by light blue)

You can also do the same thing using two mirrors. Bend two mirrors together in angle $\frac{360}{14}$ degrees and then put them on a paper. Draw anything on the paper and the thing you see in the mirrors will have 7 axes of symmetry.